# Setting gas for transaction on Ethereum when interacting with smart contract

Tags: ethereum

I am using `web3-eth-contract` package to connect to contract on Ethereum. I am executing it's methods by:

```
     contract.methods
        .methodName(ids)
        .send({
          to: address,
          from: address
        })
```

The problem is that I get:

[image]

After that I tried to add `gasLimit` there:

```
    contract.methods
        .methodName(ids)
        .send({
          to: address,
          from: address,
          gasLimit: 300000,
        })
```

and it worked fine when I use methods that require only simple arguments. When I use methods where I pass array of arguments and there are more arguments than 2 transactions are being cancelled. What should I pass to `gasLimit` or how can I estimate it so it will work every time?

Comment: Please share the method and its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The gas used to execute the transaction may depend on your parameters, so what you experience is totally reasonable.

Now, to know what `gasLimit` to set you need to know what the transaction is doing and how much gas it is expected to burn. You can take one of the following approaches:

- set the `gasLimit` very high, so that your transaction is always executed
- check the older transactions to the same contract and see how much gas they burnt
- use the [transaction format after the London Uprade](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/#post-london) and specify max ETH you are willing to pay for the transaction (`maxFeePerGas`) instead of setting `gasLimit`

Comment: If I add a very high gas like 3000000 and try to execute a method it shows very expensive gas on metamask so when people would see it they would not accept it... even if it will take less finally.
I cannot check older transactions because I pass an array or arguments there so people can put there 1 element or 100 elements, I would have to check gas price for each option which will take years

Comment: Is it a normal way that to set the gas limit manually or just ignored the value and use using the system passed value?